# Network eth0 down and won't obtain IP address after most recent 'apt updgrade'

Tags: networking, ethernet, ipv4, ubuntu-20.04

Recently, one of my headless ubuntu 20.04 systems started displaying "System restart required" at login.  As such, I did apt upgrade & apt update (not dist update).  I did not regain ssh access after restart.  Upon connecting a monitor and keyboard to it and a fresh reboot, I discovered eth0 was no longer coming up.  No problem: I just issued

```
ifconfig et0 up
```

and it did return.  But it still did not obtain an IP address.

Here are the contents of the network configuration file (/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml) :

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.6/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.2]
```

Poring through dmesg, nothing stands out at me as being wrong except this:

```
[    0.549347] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.549367] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[    0.549388] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.549500] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549509] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549510] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549511] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR01._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549545] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549550] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549552] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549553] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549586] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549593] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549594] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549596] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR03._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549627] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549632] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549633] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549634] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR04._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549665] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549670] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549671] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549673] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR05._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549704] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549709] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549710] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549711] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR06._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549742] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549748] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549749] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549750] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR07._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549782] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549787] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549788] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549789] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR08._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549823] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549829] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549830] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549831] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR09._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549862] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549868] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549869] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549870] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR10._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549900] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[    0.549905] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]

[    0.549906] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]

[    0.549907] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR11._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

I cannot say if the above represents some new or old problem.  Most of my research into that sort of error, reveals ways of making the error disappear rather than fixing it.  And again, I don't know if it's related to this problem.

Changing ethernet cable didn't help.

dmesg|egrep 'net|eth' shows this:

```
[    0.265462] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.549509] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549510] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549511] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR01._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549550] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549552] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549553] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549593] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549594] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549596] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR03._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549632] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549633] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549634] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR04._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549670] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549671] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549673] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR05._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549709] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549710] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549711] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR06._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549748] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549749] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549750] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR07._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549787] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549788] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549789] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR08._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549829] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549830] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549831] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR09._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549868] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549869] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549870] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR10._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.549905] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_CPC]
[    0.549906] No Arguments are initialized for method [_CPC]
[    0.549907] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR11._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.582001] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    1.572239] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) b4:2e:99:a2:58:77
[    1.572252] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.572342] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[   12.338807] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  151.263109] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  151.263213] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 1037.905604] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: NIC Link is Down
[ 1050.728466] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[ 1050.728566] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Each new reboot seems fine other than those messages and the fact that eth0 will not raise.  And even after reboot and 'ifconfig eth0 up' the lan does not obtain an IP address.

Since the server is well-known and provides necessary services throughout the network, I have temporarily issued the 192.168.1.6 address as secondary to the wifi, but clearly it is not ideal to have the most reliable network connection be the one not working.

ifconfig eth0 shows this:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 2600:1700:5950:3240:b62e:99ff:fea2:5877  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::b62e:99ff:fea2:5877  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:2e:99:a2:58:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 114055  bytes 10247594 (10.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 12707  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 509  bytes 69493 (69.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0x51200000-51220000
```

EDIT: syslog result from executing the following commands

```
ifconfig eth0 down && sleep 60 && ifconfig eth0 up && tail /var/log/syslog

Oct 29 14:48:56 velmicro kernel: [ 9784.175020] usb usb2-port10: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Oct 29 14:48:59 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 29 14:48:59 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address 2600:1700:5950:3240:b62e:99ff:fea2:5877.
Oct 29 14:48:59 velmicro kernel: [ 9787.610271] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: NIC Link is Down
Oct 29 14:48:59 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1700:5950:3240:b62e:99ff:fea2:5877 on eth0.

Oct 29 14:50:02 velmicro kernel: [ 9850.470210] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Oct 29 14:50:02 velmicro kernel: [ 9850.470312] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Oct 29 14:50:02 velmicro NetworkManager[947]: <info>  [1667069402.5725] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
Oct 29 14:50:04 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::b62e:99ff:fea2:5877.
Oct 29 14:50:04 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 29 14:50:04 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Registering new address record for fe80::b62e:99ff:fea2:5877 on eth0.*.
Oct 29 14:50:06 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::b62e:99ff:fea2:5877.
Oct 29 14:50:06 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address 2600:1700:5950:3240:b62e:99ff:fea2:5877.
Oct 29 14:50:06 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Registering new address record for 2600:1700:5950:3240:b62e:99ff:fea2:5877 on eth0.*.
Oct 29 14:50:06 velmicro avahi-daemon[943]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::b62e:99ff:fea2:5877 on eth0.
```

EDIT: Output from mcli does not include eth0:

```
# nmcli con
NAME                 UUID                                  TYPE  DEVICE 
ls2021.lovelady.com  a4fa8d23-a06d-4955-bfd9-5d7de76584c2  wifi  wlan0
```

Again, it was fine until that "apt upgrade"

What might I try in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: As the IP addresses are assigned by NetworkManager, not directly by the kernel, have you checked whether NetworkManager has anything in its own logs?

Comment: @user1686 - oops, thanks for the reminder.  I have now included the logs resulting from ifconfig down/up for eth0 (with a minute between for ease of identification)

Comment: That's not what I was asking about, though. ifconfig does nothing useful here – it's not part of NetworkManager, it's not part of Netplan, and it doesn't read /etc/netplan or apply any config except what's given in the command line; it just switches the interface on or off. You need either Netplan CLI or NetworkManager `nmcli` to apply the settings. Has Netplan created a NetworkManager connection profile? Does it show up in `nmcli con`?

Comment: Sorry @user1686 , NetworkManager is not my forte.  I thought that turning the interface on, would queue NetworkManager to do its work (seems it should anyway)... and I see that NetworkManager chimed in, according to that log, but didn't seem to do anything useful.  The answer to your question, though, is "apparently not."  Output from nmcli con shows only device wlan0.  I'll reiterate: this worked before the boot after latest upgrade.  Not sure if that helps, but whatever made it work then, seems to me, should make it work now.